# Adding click event to dynamically generated accordions jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a widget which consists of dynamically generated tabs. Each tab consists of 7 accordions. As I generate the tabs dynamically I add the Accordions dynamically too. No what I need is a single click handler which has an event argument that specifies which accordion has been clicked so that I can add respective data to the div of that accordion. Code looks somewhat like this

```
 <div class='tab' id='idCallDetailTab'>
        <ul>
            <?php $i=0; foreach ($this->Asp as $item) { $i++; ?>
            <li><a href="#etabs-<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $item['asp']; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <?php $i=0; foreach ($this->Asp as $item) { $i++;  ?>
            <div id="etabs-<?php echo $i; ?>" >
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                var accordian = '<div class="accordion"><h4><a href="#">CallLogin</a></h4><div id="acclogin-<?php echo $i; ?>"></div><h4><a href="#">Call Allocate</a></h4><div id="accallocate-<?php echo $i; ?>"></div><h4><a href="#">Call Attend</a></h4><div id="accattend-<?php echo $i; ?>"></div><h4><a href="#">Call Dispatched</a></h4><div id="accdispatched-<?php echo $i; ?>"></div><h4><a href="#">Call Part Indent</a></h4><div id="accindent-<?php echo $i; ?>"></div><h4><a href="#">Call transfer</a></h4><div id="acctransfer-<?php echo $i; ?>"></div><h4><a href="#">Call Part Recieved</a></h4><div id="accreceived-<?php echo $i; ?>"></div></div>';                 

                $('#etabs-<?php echo $i; ?>').html(accordian);
                $('#acclogin-<?php echo $i; ?>').html('100');
                $('#accallocate-<?php echo $i; ?>').html('200');
                $('#accattend-<?php echo $i; ?>').html('300');
                $('#accdispatched-<?php echo $i; ?>').html('400');
                $('#accindent-<?php echo $i; ?>').html('500');
                $('#acctransfer-<?php echo $i; ?>').html('600');
                $('#accreceived-<?php echo $i; ?>').html('700');
            </script>

        <?php } ?>
    </div >
```

Answer (score 2):

**Calling Ajax on Tabs Click** : 
with just setting just **href** attribute of tabs, its calling Ajax url for the particular tab divs.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ajax.html

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Preloaded</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content1.html">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content2.html">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content3-slow.php">Tab 3 (slow)</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content4-broken.php">Tab 4 (broken)</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can customize more with options here.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Answer (score 0):

Found a better approach. 
Instead of adding the accordians in the same file, I added them to another html file and loaded the content of that HTML into my tabs via ajax (well JQuery handled all the ajax loading). The only thing I had to add was applying accordian to the load event of the tabs to maintain accordian UI